# Creating an ERD and relational model design

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, relation

I need to design a small database for class, I used the following ERD model:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYD3S.jpg

and got the following relational model:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bVUh.jpg

by following a similar class example that I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to link to.

My question is did I do this correctly and if so why does the Treated table exist? Why can I not just draw the arrow from AnimalID in Animal to AnimalID in visit? Any help would be appreciated as I do not fully understand these design models.

Comment: You can (and probably should) put images directly into your question.

Comment: I actually can't I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

The ERD you showed us is a little confusing.  The Treated relationship suggests that the relationship between Animals and Visits is many to many.  That is, one animal can be treated on many visits and one visit can treat many animals.

But the inclusion of AnimalID as an attribute of a Visit suggests something different,  that only one Animal can be treated on one visit.

Your ERD mixes elements of requirements analysis and database design.  A classical ERD does not include foreign keys, and listing AnimalID as an attribute of a Visit would be incorrect in classical ERD diagramming.  Instead, the cardinalities of the Treated relationship would be explicitly shown on the diagram.

With those cardinalities one would be able to determine whether the Treated relationship is many-to-one, one-to-many, one-to-one, or many-to-many.

If many-to-many is the right answer, then your design is correct.  If many-to-one is the right answer, then your design is overly complicated, and you could store AnimalID as a foreign key in the Visit table.

Comment: Thank you, I got a similar answer asking this question elsewhere. I am going for a many-to-one relationship. Our examples use the terminology at least one, at most one, and exactly one and I am not sure which one of those corresponds to one-to-many. I do want AnimalID to be a foreign key in the visit table, but does that mean it should not be or could not be the primary key of the Animal table still?

Comment: Your ERD is also incorrect, unless they are teaching you ERD differently than the way I learned it, which is possible.  The way I learned it, Animal ID should NOT be an attribute of Visit.

Comment: A foreign key always references a primary key.  That is how the relationship is expressed.